# How to log to file using Django and Gunicorn? Using TimedRotatingFileHandler misses logs

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a Django app that logs INFO using a TimedRotatingFileHandler. In a development server that works fine but when running in production using gunicorn, not all log lines make it to the file. I also use a console handler which correctly logs everything, and looks like the file used by TimedRotatingFileHandler only has some of those lines and drops a lot of what appears from the console logger.

It also exhibits another strange behavior; my logging dictConfig has a midnight rotation. What I expected was mylog.log being written to until midnight and then rotates the content into a mylog.log. file. This is the behavior when running in development server that came with Django. What happens when running my app with gunicorn is it continuously writes into both mylog.log file and mylog.log.2022-02-01 file. The content inside mylog.log does not appear in the other file as well. It's almost as if log is being distributed between mylog.log and mylog.log.2022-02-01 throughout the day...

My config:

```
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': mylog.log,
            'when': 'midnight',
            'encoding': 'utf-8',
            'backupCount': 7,
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': level,
        },
    },
```

Is the problem due to gunicorn workers being run in a different process and TimedRotatingFileHandler doesn't work with multiprocessing? Or bad config?

What is the "standard" or suggested way to log to file while inside a request handler within Django, while the app is running on gunicorn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because Python doesn't support coordination between writing to one file from multiple processes, so stuff could get overwritten. I would use either a `SocketHandler` or a `QueueHandler` for all the Django and your webapp modules, and have a separate process listening {either a socket receiver or a `QueueListener`) which writes to the `TimedRotatingFileHandler`. The official documentation [has a cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) which shows recipes for the multiple process scenario, including working code for socket receivers etc. which you can adapt to your specific needs. I use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html) to keep the listener process running.